# Automatic e-mail processing

Tags: .net, email, outlook

I'd like to write a .NET application in F# to automate some of the processing of my e-mails. For example, when an order comes in my program might compute a new htpasswd from the e-mail's contents, upload it to our web server and reply to the customer with login details.

How do people do this? I've tried Outlook 2007 automation but it just prompts the user for security and my attempts to get it to stop doing this have failed so I cannot automate anything with it. Is there a .NET-friendly e-mail client I can use more easily?

This has been so tedious that I'm seriously considering writing my own .NET-friendly e-mail client...

Comment: Are you sure you want to use F# for this? Wouldn't C# be more appropriate?

Comment: How would C# be more appropriate? It is worse than F# at every aspect of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common scenario.  The most common is to use IMAP or POP3 components to download the email and parse using a Mime component.  I've got an IMAP windows service that I've had running for 8+yrs now that processes emails.

I wrote and use my own stuff at [www.advancedintellect.com](http://www.advancedintellect.com) , but if you want free components, there are some codeproject articles out there, along with some projects on sourceforge.

Answer (score 1):

A few links for you to consider to bypass the security dialog:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/926512
- http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/ork2003/HA011402911033.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Those links explain the problem I was having: if you buy Outlook for £99 then its .NET "automation" requires manual intervention unless you spend another $700 on Microsoft Exchange Server. I haven't been impressed with Outlook 2007 (it just crashed again) so I'm not sure I want to be dependent upon such expensive software...